# Bad Access at UIApplicationMain() if Keyboard's Correction is set to Default or Yes

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, exc-bad-access, program-entry-point

In my project, there is a simple table view and search controller. Everything loads and works fine, until I type into the text field. It then crashes at `UIApplicationMain()`, with a stack track of several `UIKeyboardInputImpl` methods. On a whim, I decided to mess with the settings in IB for the Search Bar itself—turns out, setting the option for Correction to *Default* or *Yes* causes the crash. I've never seen this happen before, and I'm tempted to call this a bug in the SDK. Can anyone confirm or provide more insight?

Xcode 4 Project:
http://db.tt/V6POWik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug in the SDK…not much that I can do.

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded and checked your sample project for all available options of `Correction` and it didn't crash. You should try cleaning your build and derived data just in case and try again. If you are sure that the problem is reproducible I would love to know the steps I need to take to reproduce the error/crash.

Comment: I did do a Clean. It's easy for me to reproduce—just change the Correction setting. If you can't repro, I suppose it's a bug in Xcode or the SDK.

Comment: You're probably right about this. How about `filing a bug` then?

Comment: @Inspire48 do you have the link to the bug report you made?

Comment: Unfortunately no; I had forgotten that I was using beta software (as long as it doesn't crash it just becomes part of your routine…), and so the report isn't filed in the public repository and is most likely under NDA. Sorry!